# VBA Macro changing macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is it possible to create a macro in MS Office (in this case Word) that will change other macro code? I was trying to find information but no results.

I have a doc which works as a template. Content of template is changed and then saved to another file. However it is important to have current date in it. It cannot be self-updated. Those docs go to folder of people and it is important to know when they get the document, so it must be simply data (or something that does not update).

I was thinking about an on-start event macro that would input current date and on exit it would ask "Do you want self-update functionality" Yes / No

If Yes, delete that event. However I have no idea if it is possible. If it is I still don't know how to search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. In VBA, unlike some lower level languages when you define an event you can not disable it, even using other VBA code.

In C# or VB.NET, Java or C++ you can disable an event by un-wiring it from the handler, but this is not possible in VBA.

Maybe if you be more clear on what you need I can give you a better answer.

Comment: Hm... I guess this is anwser to my question if it goes for "macro changing macro". I'll try to think more about how I can achieve what I want and if nothing will come to my head I will ask another question.